# filter observations with date near to other date

Tags: r

I want to filter dates which lies close to other date (+5 days).

```
 d <- wrapr::build_frame( "ID","DATE2", "DATE" | 1 , "2001-01-02" , "2001-01-05" | 2 , "2001-01-02" , "2015-04-25" | 3 , "2001-01-02" , "2000-04-01" | 4 , "2014-01-02" , "2014-03-29" | 5 , "2001-01-02" , "2001-01-02" | 6 , "2001-01-02" , "2005-06-16" )

  ID      DATE2       DATE
1  1 2001-01-02 2001-01-05
2  2 2001-01-02 2015-04-25
3  3 2001-01-02 2000-04-01
4  4 2014-01-02 2014-03-29
5  5 2001-01-02 2001-01-02
6  6 2001-01-02 2005-06-16
```

Should generate this:

```
ID      DATE2       DATE
1  1 2001-01-02 2001-01-05
2  4 2014-01-02 2014-03-29
3  5 2001-01-02 2001-01-02
```

I want to use dplyr - `d%>%filter(DATE= etc...)` if possible.

Thanks ;)
/H

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `filter`. I'm not sure why you think `2014-01-02` is within 5 days of `2014-03-29` thought.

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c("DATE2","DATE")),
            list(~as.Date(.))) %>%
  dplyr::filter(abs(DATE - DATE2) <= 5)
#  ID      DATE2       DATE
#1  1 2001-01-02 2001-01-05
#2  5 2001-01-02 2001-01-02
```

Comment: Thanks. That´s a typo - should be 2014-04-02

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`

```
subset(d, abs(as.Date(DATE2) - as.Date(DATE)) <=5)
```

---

For the second condition

```
subset(d, (as.Date(DATE) - as.Date(DATE2)) <=3)
```